# python variable returns None even if variable can be printed right before the return statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, return, return-value

This is a part of a simple tokenizer and parser. I don't understand why the `get_token()` is returning None even if `token_value` is successfully printed right before
`return "returning: " + token_value`.

```py
s = "int i = 2; i <= n; i += 5)"
cursor = 0

def is_string(c):
    return c.isalnum() or c == "_"

def has_more_tokens():
    return cursor < len(s)

def get_token():
    global cursor
    token_value = ""

    string = s[cursor: ]
    if not has_more_tokens():
        return
    if string[0] == " ":
        cursor += 1
        get_token()
        return
    if is_string(string[0]):
        token_value = ""
        for char in string: # extract the whole expression <int x = a + b;>
            if char in [";", ",", ")"]:
                cursor += 1
                break
            token_value += char
            cursor += 1
        print("before returning: ",token_value)
        return "returning: " + token_value
    return "error"

while has_more_tokens():
    print(get_token())
    print()
```

Comment: Can you debug further? Try adding a statement after each of the empty `return` ex: `return "nothing"` just for debugging purposes and tell me the output.

Comment: @AlyMobarak Hello I've figured it out!. I should have returned `get_token()` under the second if statement. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the result from `get_token()` is not returned when it is recursively called. Thus, it returns `None`.

fixed this section:

```py
if string[0] == " ":
        cursor += 1
        return get_token() #fix here
```